# How to execute python script from another python script and send it's output in text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script test.py which is used for server automation task and have other script server.py which list out all  server name.

server.py list all sevrer name in text.log file and this log file is used by test.py as a input.

I want one single script test.py to execute server.py from inside it and also redirect server.py script output to text.log file as well.

So far i have tried with execfile("server.py") >text.log in test.py which didn't worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) with `stdout` argument:

```
import subprocess
import sys

with open('text.log', 'w') as f:
    subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'server.py'], stdout=f)
    # ADD stderr=subprocess.STDOUT  if you want also catch standard error output
```